# Blocking network requests in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webkit, dom-events

I'm looking for an IE equivalent of the `beforeload` event handler in webkit - I need to inspect network requests and selectively block them, ideally in Javascript. There are some other options outside of the browser that I'm aware of, namely MIME filtering and such, but I would really prefer to do this in Javascript if possible.

Copied from my comment below - For instance, I would want to insert Javascript onto `example.com` that prevents it from making requests to `badwebsitesrus.com`. I have the code to insert the Javascript, but can't find a suitable API to do the blocking.

Comment: What type of criteria do you need to block them, and how are you incorporating this JavaScript code?

Comment: My crystal ball foresees that this looks like an XY problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to inspect? The packages or where the request comes from. When you talk about Javascript, it is sometimes limited for server side of things. So you should provide more information as to what you are exactly wanting to inspect

Comment: I'm trying to block network requests originating from the page - for instance, I want to insert javascript (via a BHO) that prevents example.com from making requests to badwebsitesrus.com.

Comment: They have a separate C++ component that they communicate to that uses native browser APIs to block requests. They were written a long time, ago, so I was hoping that maybe MS would have added some new in-browser javascript options that would obviate the need for unstable native hooks.